# defaultPieSliceColorForINdex:index not returning proper color value: coreplot

Tags: iphone, core-plot, pie-chart

I am trying to use below delegate method to draw data label

```
-(CPTLayer *) dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{  
    CPTTextLayer *label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", index]];  
    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [label.textStyle mutableCopy];  
    textStyle.color = [CPTPieChart defaultPieSliceColorForIndex:index];  
    label.textStyle=textStyle;  
    return label;  
}
```

the output I am getting is something like this:
[image: see image]

so you can see the differences:

- slice 0 data label is of color red but should be yellow.
- slice 3 data label is of color yellow but should be magenta.

I could acheive this by `switch(index)`, but why its not working this way?
Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels are the correct colors—it's the pie slices that don't match the default colors. What values do the other datasource methods return?

The default colors are:

```
Index   RGB                   Color
------------------------------------------
  0     (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)       Red
  1     (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)       Green
  2     (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)       Blue
  3     (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)       Yellow
  4     (0.25, 0.5, 0.25)     Dark green
  5     (1.0, 0.0, 1.0)       Magenta
  6     (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)       Gray
  7     (0.25, 0.5, 0.0)      Medium green
  8     (0.25, 0.25, 0.25)    Dark gray
  9     (0.0, 1.0, 1.0)       Cyan
```

Comment: thanks for reply!My dumbness i thought that defaultPieSliceColorForIndex:index would return the default color of my slices automatically on to data label color.I am controlling each pie slice color in sliceForPieChart delegate method.Thanks for additional info.:)